# SCSS include ".classnames" from npm package in your local ".scss" file

Tags: vue.js, sass, quasar-framework

I'm using [Quasar Framework](https://quasar.dev) (vue.js), and instead of writing helper classes directly into the HTML, I would like to reuse those class names inside the actual custom .class definition.

`@use`, `@import` does not working. here is my code:

```
<template>
  <q-card class=".customclass">
    This should be styled
  </q-card>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
@import url('./node_modules/quasar/src/css/variables.sass'); // <-- not working
@use './node_modules/quasar/src/css/variables.sass'; // <-- not working
.customclass {
  // I want to use those classes: q-pa-md bg-grey-1 text-grey-8 no-shadow border-color-grey-8
  @extend .no-shadow; // not working
}
</style>
```

I would like to reuse those classes inside my `.classname`:

```
.q-pa-md
.bg-grey-1
.text-grey-8
.no-shadow
.border-color-grey-8
```

Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to import the main quasar sass files using

```
@import "~quasar/dist/quasar.sass";
```

And the rest will then work as you want

Answer (score 0):

1. For static classes, please use class property without a dot:

```html
  <q-card class="customclass"></q-card>
```

2. Usually Quasar components have a few built-in styling properties.
   In your case, please try "flat" attribute - this will remove the shadow for [QCard component](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/card#Basic):

```html
  <q-card flat>
    a QCard component without shadow
  </q-card>
```

3. If you still need to use certain Quasar SCSS classes, please attach them
    in your template as [static or dynamic classes](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#object-syntax):

```html
  <q-card class="customclass no-shadow">
    static classes
  </q-card>

  <q-card :class="{ 'no-shadow': isActive }">
    dynamic classes
  </q-card>

  <q-card :class="['customclass', { 'no-shadow': isActive }]">
    static + dynamic classes
  </q-card>
```

4. Extending SCSS styles with Quasar SCSS mixins seems to be impossible at this moment.
   I found a few feature requests for it, but both were closed.

Comment: that's not exactly what I was asking for, but thanks for that information